# Why is the Ricci scalar non-zero in this case?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

The Einstein equations can be written as (1):
$$R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab} = -8\pi GT_{ab}$$

or by contracting the above equation with the metric tensor and resubstituting: (2)
$$R_{ab}=8\pi G(\frac{1}{2}Tg_{ab}-T_{ab}).$$

In a vacuum, equation (1) reduces to $R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}Rg_{ab}=0$ and equation (2) reduces to $R_{ab}=0$, which implies that in a vacuum, $R=0$.

However, if I explicitly calculate $R$ for a plane wave of the form 
$$h_{ab} = A_{ab}\exp(ikx)$$ (the Minkowski metric $\eta_{ab}$ perturbed by $h_{ab}$),
I obtain: $$R=k^ak^bh_{ab}-k^\lambda k_\lambda h\ \ ,$$ where $h=\eta_{ab}h^{ab}$, which looks like some sort of wave equation, but is nonzero. It's supposed to be $0$ but is not. Why?

Comment: The Ricci scalar is zero for a gravitational wave, as is any curvature scalar. See Hans-Juergen Schmidt, "Why do all the curvature invariants of a gravitational wave vanish?" http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9404037 . The fact that you get a nonvanishing Ricci scalar tells us that your metric is not a gravitational wave in vacuum, or that you made a mistake in your calculation.

Answer (score 5):

Gravitational waves are transverse and travel along null rays.  Thus, you have to have $k^{a} h_{ab} = 0$ and $k^a k_a = 0$.  (More accurately, the transversality condition can be viewed as a gauge condition:  we can always apply a local diffeomorphism such that this first condition is true.)  Under these conditions, the Ricci scalar does indeed vanish—as should the Ricci tensor, if you've done everything correctly.  But a completely arbitrary wave-like metric with an arbitrary polarization $h_{ab}$ and propagation vector $k_a$ will not, as you've found, satisfy Einstein's equation in vacuum.

Comment: Hmm but $R$ is gauge invariant, so you shouldn't need to impose any transversality condition to ensure it vanishes, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: It's just like how Maxwell's equations imply that the photon polarizations are transverse.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The plane wave ansatz given in the question is only a solution to the (linearised) vacuum Einstein equations *in transverse gauge*. If we move out of this gauge, the form of the metric changes, and so $R$ picks up extra terms that cancel the now non-vanishing $k^a h_{ab}$.